# How to include multiple bitmaps into a global arraylist?

Tags: c++, arraylist, bitmap, tizen, tizen-native-app

I have an `ArrayList` as a member variable of a class which should be intialized with a bitmap object when the function, `OnImageDecodeUrlReceived()` and the whole list should be used in another function, `OnCreate()` later. But since the bitmap objects are local to `OnImageDecodeUrlReceived()`, the object gets out of scope and wont be available in `OnCreate()`.
How to make the bitmap objects visible outside the function?

Comment: You could construct a new `Bitmap` that is a copy of the received one, and add the copy to the `ArrayList`.

Comment: I tried to do that by using 'new Bitmap(oldBitmapObject)' but it seems to generate an error saying 'cannot call a private constructor'. Please specify if there's any other method.

Comment: I mean using the `Construct` method. Refer to [the documentation for `Bitmap`](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.tizen.native.apireference%2FclassTizen_1_1Graphics_1_1Bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the bitmap pointers in the arraylist ,Don't delete the pointers within `OnImageDecodeUrlReceived()`

Eg:

Define arrayList as

```
ArrayListT<Bitmap*> yourList;

void YourClass::OnImageDecodeUrlReceived(RequestId reqId,
    Tizen::Graphics::Bitmap* pBitmap, result r,
    const Tizen::Base::String errorCode,
    const Tizen::Base::String errorMessage)
{
     yourList.Add(pBitmap);
}
```

Clear the arrayList and delete those bitmap pointers after use

Comment: Still I cant display the images from the ArrayListT! When the image is loaded to a Bitmap* object at OnCreate() using GetAt(index,bitmapObject) the application closes unexpectedly.

Comment: Is bitmap object a local variable of the OnImageDecodeUrlReceived()? If that's so, the objects must be loosing scope and should get deleted automatically after the scope of the function. In that case what can be done to make same bitmap image extend its scope?

Comment: You should look in to the pointer handling, Bitmap* will not loose its scope unless you delete the pointer, you should keep pointers it in the arrayList, could you post your code , including arrayList.add get declaration and usage

Answer (score 0):

I created array of Bitmap objects(not pointer objects) in the class and later copied the Bitmap in OnImageDecodeUrlReceived() to those objects in array using Construct. Now it works fine.